# Function names in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have here the list of default functions in Wordpress and my own description

- post_title - title of the post `<?php the_title(); ?>`
- post_content - the content `<?php the_content(); ?>`
- post_excerpt - it's excerpt `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`
- post_date - published date
- post_category - category
- post_tag - it's tags
- post_author - the author of the post
- featured_image - chosen featured image

Anyway, what my concern is, I'm looking for the Function names of Wordpress SEO by YOAST and the All in ONE SEO PACK Wordpress plugin?

**Wordpress SEO by YOAST Plugin**
If I want to display the following below in my post? what php code should I use?

- Focus Keyword - `<?php the_??? (); ?>`
- SEO Title - `<?php the_??? (); ?>`
- Meta Description - `<?php the_??? (); ?>`

**All in ONE SEO PACK Wordpress plugin**

- Title - `<?php the_??? (); ?>`
- Description - `<?php the_??? (); ?>`
- Keywords - `<?php the_??? (); ?>`

**I need to know how can I display it at the bottom of my published post. example the focus keyword of Wordpress SEO by Yoast, I want it to display it after the content.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not clear but you may look in to the plugin source and seek help in the plugin's forum/site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for a third party product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these functions

Frontend

```
wpseo_head
Runs at the end of the output of all SEO meta tags by the plugin, before the closing debug comment.
wpseo_opengraph
Runs at the end of the output of OpenGraph meta tags by the plugin, before the closing debug comment.
wpseo_do_sitemap_<$type>
Runs in the creation of XML sitemaps, $type can not be a valid post type or taxonomy, when they are this action will not trigger.
```

for more here is a link http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/api/